Install snapd fails on /usr/lib/snapd/snap-update-ns.dpkg-new': No such f ile or directory
So I returned to my Ubuntu 24.04 machine today an none of my snaps worked. After trying too many thinks I went for remove and install. Guess I should have documented all steps taken...
Now, installing snap seems to work, but snapd fails
sudo apt install snap snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
snap is already the newest version (2013-11-29-11).
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  snapd
The following held packages will be changed:
  snapd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/28,1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 110 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 282075 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.63+24.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.63+24.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.63+24.04_amd64.de
b (--unpack):
 error setting timestamps of '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-update-ns.dpkg-new': No such f
ile or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the loc
al system
         dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.63+24.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

The directory /usr/lib/snapd/ does not exist. I'm pretty stuck here :-(

see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1520623/1698042

Thanks for pointing me to that @TalaatEtman. Will follow that topic. As for your solution there, that didn't work for me.
